# Java code what is wrong with this?

Tags: java

I am really new to programming, on netbeans i have deleted all the other text, all i have is the following, Why wont the program run?

The error i get is, no main Class found.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package findcost2;
 public class Main 

 /* a program to calculate and display the cost of a product after 
  * sales tax has been added*/

public class FindCost2
        Public static void main (String[] args)
{
      double price,tax;
      price = 500;
      tax = 17.5;
      price = price * (1 + tax/100);// calculate cost
      // display results
      System.out.println("***Product Price Check");
      System.out.println("Cost after tax = " + price);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised you were able to run it!

Answer (score 3):

Try this exactly and name your java file FindCost2.java

```
package findcost2;

public class FindCost2{

public static void main (String[] args)
{
  double price,tax;
  price = 500;
  tax = 17.5;
  price = price * (1 + tax/100);// calculate cost
  // display results
  System.out.println("***Product Price Check");
  System.out.println("Cost after tax = " + price);
}

}
```

Comment: gives this error now - init:
deps-jar:
Compiling 2 source files to C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\FindCost2\build\classes
C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\FindCost2\src\findcost2\Main.java:3: class FindCost2 is public, should be declared in a file named FindCost2.java
public class FindCost2{
1 error
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds

Comment: in your netbeans, right click on the folder and create a package named as findcost2 and then move this file into that package. Hint think of packages as folders.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a curly bracket after `class Main` and you have two public classes in the same source file.  Delete `public class Main` and change `Public` to `public`.

You should probably also use [decimal numbers for dealing with currencies](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/07/MoneyInJava.html)

> Sooner or later, everyone trying to calculate money in Java discovers that computers can't add.

Comment: You've also got a dangling `public class Main` up top that doesn't need to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Why is `Public` capitalized? Shoud be:

```
public class FindCost2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Numerous problems with this code:

1. The outer class (*Main*) does not have an opening bracket. Insert the *{* bracket.
2. The inner class (*FindCost2*) does not have an opening bracket. Insert the *{* bracket.
3. The public modifier for the main method is capitalized. Start with a lowercase *p*.
4. The main method is nested in an inner class. This is really bad form. To make it work anyway, the inner class needs to be static. Insert the *static* keyword.

When put like this, it compiles:

```
public class Main {

/*
 * a program to calculate and display the cost of a product after sales tax
 * has been added
 */

public static class FindCost2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double price, tax;
        price = 500;
        tax = 17.5;
        price = price * (1 + tax / 100);// calculate cost
        // display results
        System.out.println("***Product Price Check");
        System.out.println("Cost after tax = " + price);
    }
}
}
```

However, there is absolutely no point to the outer class (*Main*). Just delete this. When the outer class is removed, the inner class (*FindCost2*) need not be static anymore. Remove the keyword.

It is really bad form to declare multiple variables on one line (as in double price, tax;). Split that to two lines:

```
double price;
double tax;
```

There are good reasons not to use the double type for monetary values. With a little extra work, you can easily write a simple Money class. Check [javapractices.com](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=6D7444C15C2A49BFED9A99EB1585F1AD?Id=13) for a good overview on that.

Hope that helps!